# How well can you approximate a function by a band-restricted function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Say I have a compactly supported $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. 
Let $R>0$. Let $\nu$ be some reasonable measure on $\mathbb{R}$ -- take, for instance, (a) $d\nu(t)=dt$ or (b) $d\nu(t)=e^{-t}$ for $t>0$ and $d\nu(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$.

Let $\delta(R)$ be the minimum of $|f-\widehat{g}|_2 = \left( \int_\mathbb{R} |f(t)-\widehat{g}(t)|^2 d\nu(t)\right)^{1/2}$ over all functions $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ supported on $\lbrack -R,R\rbrack$.

What is $\delta(R)$? How fast does it decrease as $R\to \infty$? Given $R$, can one construct a $g$ that attains the minimum?

(A variation on the same question: allow measures, not just functions $g$, supported on $\lbrack -R,R\rbrack$.)

Update: for $d\nu(t) = t$ this is very easy by isometry, as mentioned below; the minimum is attained for $g$ equal to the restriction of $\widehat{f}$ to $\lbrack -R,R\rbrack$ -- and so, if $f$ is in $C^k$, $\delta(R)$ decreases at least as fast as $1/R^{k-1}$ as $R\to \infty$. I am really more interested in the answers for the measure $\nu$ given in (b) above.

Comment: Really? $\widehat g$ is entire if $g$ is compactly supported, so we do not have any choice at all as to what to take for $g$ and most of the time we have no possibility to find such $g$ with any $R$. I hope you meant something else or I just misunderstood what is written...

Comment: Hm, I guess I really had (b) in mind. Let me rewrite this...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in case (a) (Lebesgue measure), $|f-\widehat{g}|_2 = |\widehat{f}-g|_2$ by Plancherel, so shouldn't you just take $g$ to be the restriction of $\widehat{f}$ to $[-R,R]$?

Comment: I was about to say, yes, for (a) this is trivial by isometry. But what can one say about (b), say?

Comment: Fourier uncertainity might be the right key word, but I guess you know that already. Does $\delta(R)$ not depend on $f$ apriori? I guess you believe that the asymptotic is independant of $f$?

Comment: I am looking for estimates that would depend on $f$ only in a coarse sense - by depending only on a norm of $f$, or on whether $f$ is in $C^k$, say.

Comment: $e^{-t}\chi_{t>0}\\,dt$ is also trivial: polynomials are dense in the corresponding $L^2$ space and those are Fourier transforms of distributions with one-point support (the origin). Smearing a bit, we see that we can approximate as well as we want with $g$ supported in an arbitrary neighborhood of the origin. 

Comment: Sorry for the crazy LaTeX. Apparently it works differently in comments. I meant $e^{-t}\chi_{\{t>0\}}dt$

Comment:  I don't see this. Polynomials aren't Fourier transforms of distributions with one-point support. Yes, linear combinations of exponentials $e^{itr}$, $r$  real (these are the Fourier transforms of distributions with one-point support), do look dense with respect to that measure, but obviously the support is $\{r\}$. So, the question would be - are they still dense if we restrict $r$ to be in $\lbrack -R,R \rbrack$?

Comment: (If we were talking about functions $x^r$ ($r$ real), then I take we probably would be fine with a restriction of r to [−R,R], by some variation of the Muntz-Szasz theorem.) 

Comment: ---Polynomials aren't Fourier transforms of distributions with one-point support.--- Take the Dirac delta measure at the origin. What is the Fourier transform? Now differentiate a few times (which is equivalent to the multiplication by $ix$ on the Fourier side). What do you get?

Comment: Oops - was thinking of measures. Thanks. On the other hand, while this is applicable to the original proble, it is rather expensive - and that shows that the right formulation of the problem involves yet another norm...


Comment: (expensive in the context of the original problem, which I haven't really stated here)


Comment: Yeah, half of the fun here is to figure out how to state the problem meaningfully :). Unfortunately, so far you are the only person who knows what all that is really about, so I cannot help with this in any way...

Comment: You've already helped some, thanks.